# Is there some way I can encapsulate the error messages from the business logic tier to the presentation tier?

Tags: asp.net-core, n-tier-architecture

Anything else helps me limit the throw exception in asp net core!

Comment: Do you need a custom exception handler web page? Check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/60669764/2858407

Comment: not really, something like https://dev.to/sam_ferree/avoiding-exceptions-in-aspnet-core-lb4 => but i don't understand about that